# Is it possible to only use Google Apps for Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I am interested in using Gmail via Google apps for my domain. I have had success with the emails but not with the website portion. My question is would it be possible to only use Gmail Google Apps as opposed to migrating entirely to Google?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. You can use only the Google products you want, and leave the rest unused. It is merely a matter of DNS records.

For using Gmail, you need to [set the correct MX records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140034). If you don't want to use Google Sites for your website, you don't have to do anything else - your current website will stay unchanged, while your Google Sites will be available at http://sites.google.com/a/yourdomain.com

If you want to completely [disable](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=45691) Google Sites (or other Google Apps services), you may do so from   the Google Apps control panel.

Comment: Thanks Vidar, that is just what I need. By the way, if you don't mind me asking, what are Google Sites?

Comment: Glad I could help. Google Sites is a service of Google Apps which provides a simple CMS for websites. So, if you like, you could build your website in Google Sites. Although I wouldn't recommend using it for your company's public web site, because the design possibilties are limited. But as an intranet, company wiki, or documentation base, it is quite useful, especially if employees already use Gmail, because you get single sign-on across Google services. See http://www.google.com/sites/overview.html for more about Google Sites.