# Can you use Google Apps for Business without Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

If a company has an established mail server setup, which they do not want to abandon, can you use Google Apps for Business just for the other services?

I would guess that you can, but would require an alternate email domain for Google Apps, and perhaps configure forwarding to the existing email addresses?

Are there any other technical gotchas?

Comment: You can do so, just configure the MX records to give your existing mail servers higher priority than Google's servers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**.

As Sathya says, you could configure the MX records to give your existing servers priority, *or just leave the MX records as they are* for your domain. Then email will continue to be delivered to your existing servers.

You will probably also want to disable the Gmail service completely. This is done in the Google Apps Control panel, at `https://admin.google.com/`. If you don't do this, then your users will have access to it via the URL `mail.google.com` or via the Apps launcher, causing confusion.

Also see [Is it possible to only use Google Apps for email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/32057/is-it-possible-to-only-use-google-apps-for-gmail/32058#32058), which is somewhat similar.